# Pending Comments

Tags: comments

How get ID all pending comments wp ? I want realizate via loop php, but i do not how get it.

wp_get_comment_status - function is returend only trash', 'approved', 'unapproved', 'spam' status.

Comment: I'd guess 'unapproved' are the pending ones. Can you find a comment in pending then check its status in the database?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) will get comments for you, either from all across a blog or for a specific post. Its arguments are documented at [`WP_Comment_Query::__construct()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/).

Unless you've installed a plugin that adds `pending` as a comment status, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
$args = array(
     // Limits comments to a specific post.
     // Leave this off if you want all comments, blog-wide.
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    // Get only non-approved (ie, pending) comments.
    'status'  => 'hold',
    // Will only fetch comment IDs.
    // If you want full comment objects, leave this off.
    'fields'  => 'ids',
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

If you *have* installed a plugin that adds `pending` as a status, you can try using `'status' => 'pending'` instead of `'status' => 'hold'`, since the `status` argument will allow custom statuses.